# Arduino behaves strangely when reading utf8 via Serial

Tags: c++, c, string, utf-8, arduino

I run into some strange behavior when sending some uft8 encoded String to my arduino. I started of with [this](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SerialEvent) example and modified it. My program works as follows:

I'm listening for the SerialEvent according to the example. By way of this, I'm not adding characters to a String, but to a char[500] array in a round robin fashion. There are two pointer variables, one for the reading and one for the writing, which are both incremented to 499 and then set back to 0.

```
void serialEvent() {
    while (Serial.available()) {
        // get the new byte:
        char inChar = (char)Serial.read();

        // add it to the inputString:
        if (inChar != '\r') {
            if (inChar == '\n') {
                commandsInQueue++;
                inChar = NULL;
            }
            inputBuffer[ptrInputWrite] = inChar;
            if (ptrInputWrite < 499) ptrInputWrite++; else ptrInputWrite = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Then there is a reader inside of the loop function. There it creates a String from that array and hands it over to a decoder function by reference. In there, I'm using the indexOf function of the String to split the command into it's parts.

```
if (commandsInQueue > 0) {
    String tmp = "";
    tmp.reserve(500);
    do {
        tmp += inputBuffer[ptrInputRead];
        if (ptrInputRead < 499) ptrInputRead++; else ptrInputRead = 0;
    } while (inputBuffer[ptrInputRead] != NULL);

    rxInterpreter(tmp);

    if (ptrInputRead < 499) ptrInputRead++; else ptrInputRead = 0;
    commandsInQueue--;
}
```

Decoder:

```
void rxInterpreter(String cmd) {
    unsigned int lastSem = 2, nextSem = NULL;

    Serial.println("Processing command: " + cmd);

    if (connectionOpen) {
        switch (cmd[0])
        {
        // ...
        case 'T':
            textRefreshTime = millis();
            refreshBar = true;
            currentPos = 0;
            displayShift = 0;
            currentlyShowing = 0;

            {
                unsigned short len = cmd.length();
                for (short i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    if ((unsigned long)cmd[i] > 255) {
                        unsigned long chr = (unsigned short)cmd[i] << 8 | (byte)cmd[i + 1];
                        switch (chr) {
                        case 0xc384: //Ä
                        case 0xc3a4: //ä
                            cmd[i] = (uint8_t)B11100001; break;
                        case 0xc396: //Ö
                        case 0xc3b6: //ö
                            cmd[i] = (uint8_t)B11101111; break;
                        case 0xc39c: //Ü
                        case 0xc3bc: //ü
                            cmd[i] = (uint8_t)B11110101; break;
                        case 0xc39f: //ß
                            cmd[i] = (uint8_t)B11100010; break;
                        default:
                            Serial.println("Unbekanntes Zeichen " + String(chr, HEX));
                        }

                        cmd.remove(i + 1, 1);
                        len--;
                    }
                }
            }
// ...
```

Part of that process is to interpret the utf8: My first approach was to just look for the [bit signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) of utf8 chars by checking, if the value of the current char is greater than 0xC0. This didn't work. After researching a little bit, I realized, that for some reason, the char returned from that position isn't 8, but 16 bits long. So cmdString[i] would usually return a byte, but if the character is an uft8 char, then it'll return to signed shorts in a row, where the upper two octets are filled with ones.

For example the a umlaut (ä), which has the utf8 code 0xc3a4. I would expect cmdString[i] to be 0xc3 and cmdString[i+1] to be 0xa4. However, in reality, [i] returns 0xffc3 (-61 in decimal) and [i+1] 0xffa4 (-92 in decimal). As it interprets these values as signed variables, checking, if they are greater than 0xc0 fails naturally.

I tested that by printing `Serial.println(String(cmdString[i], HEX));` resp. `BINARY`. It always returned 4/16 digits, instead of 2/8.

Can somebody explain to me, why this happens? Has it something to do with the way I (respectively the arduino library) creates string objects from a byte array? I always thought, that a char is an unsigned byte under all circumstances. Is that even a bug, that I discovered?

I already worked around that issue in my code. But I still wonder why this happens.

Comment: a char is not an unsigned 8 bit value, nor is it a signed 8 bit value, since this is implementation-dependent.  most compilers even provide a command line switch for that.

Comment: I suggest you to use `unsigned char`. If you use `char` the values from 0x80 to 0xFF are managed as negative values. It's not possible a `char` is more than 8 bits, if it is greater than 8 bit may be you are using `wchar`.

Comment: "[i] returns 0xffc3" How do you know this? Is this the value you get from the debugger or something you printed with a function like printf? More likely, the function actually does return `0xC3` and `0xA4` respectively. These will be interpreted as negative decimal values in case `char` is treated as signed by your compiler. If the actual values matter, you should not use `char` but rather `uint8_t`.

Comment: If a `char` is (for some reasons) promoted to `int` the `char` values "greater" than 0x80 are displayed as 0xFFnn (where nn is the HEX value of the char).

Comment: How do you insert the utf8 values into the variable `cmdString`?

Comment: Arduino serial read method internally uses explicity defined unsigned char fields. Then unsigned char is converted to int and returned - there is no sign problem with this method.

Comment: @Lundin I highlighted the code line above. I was using Serial.println.

Comment: @SergioFormiggini It must be something like `char inChar = (char)Serial.read(); if(inChar == '\r') return; if(inChar == '\n') inChar = NULL; myBuffer[writePointer] = inChar;` and inside the loop function `decoder(String(myBuffer[readPointer]));`. I don't have the code in front of me right now. I have to check it this evening.

Comment: inChar is a `char`; a `char` represent the minimal byte dimension the CPU manages (also the minimal byte dimension of Intel CPUs is 8 bit - 64 bits CPU too); The char, on the AVR micro, CANNOT contain 16 bits ... aboveall because AVR are 8 bits processor! (if you try to execute `Serial.println(sizeof(char))` you may verify that. Thus I think the issue is a promotion to `int` due to a printout format inside the function you use to print the data. (You should have the source; It's in the Arduino suite in the module that contains `Serial.println`.)

Comment: If you see the file `Print.cpp` in the Arduino suite, you will understand why when you use `println(char, HEX)` you obtain an `int` as printout. You simply have to follow the code of the function: `size_t Print::println(unsigned char b, int base)`. :)

Comment: @SergioFormiggini Thank you for your explanation. I'll check that out when I'm back home.

Comment: @SergioFormiggini Here's the actual code: `void serialEvent() {
 while (Serial.available()) {
  // get the new byte:
  unsigned char inChar = (unsigned char)Serial.read();

  // add it to the inputString:
  if (inChar != '\r') {
   if (inChar == '\n') {
    commandsInQueue++;
    inChar = NULL;
   }
   inputBuffer[ptrInputWrite] = inChar;
   if (ptrInputWrite < 499) ptrInputWrite++; else ptrInputWrite = 0;
  }
 }
}`

Comment: @SergioFormiggini I tried it with the unsigned char, but after I changed it, my code didn't work anymore. After the change, it printed all text as endless numbers.

Comment: I think the issue is in the `Serial.println()` function. If you follow the function following the correct overloading you find this code: `size_t Print::print(unsigned char b, int base)
{
  return print((unsigned long) b, base);
}`, such a code demonstrates you that the `char` is casted as `unsigned long` before it is printed out.

Comment: A `char` (8 bit with sign) cannot have a value greater then 127 ... It's better you insert your code into the question with the apposite format, thus we may help you to solve the problem, Looking at your code, I don't see how and where you printout the values of the char the SW receives. Keep in mind that `unsigned char` has values between 0 and 255 and `char` (signed) has values between -128 e 127.

Comment: Ok! I see you have inserted your code!

Comment: @SergioFormiggini So is it a flaw in the Arduino library, that it does handle `unsigned char` that way? Writing those unsigned chars to the LCD didn't work as well. It just printed gibberish when I changed it.

Comment: The problem of the library affects only a printed output, not the memory you use to store data.

Comment: @SergioFormiggini I understand that. But is it possible, that the NewLiquidCrystal library does something similar? Or is it the String constructor, that messes everything up? Because I never print that array directly; I'm always converting and storing it into a string first.

Comment: The code contains some errors. The first thing I suggest you to interpret data into the for inside the function `rxInterpreter` using something like this: `
    unsigned char c[2] = {0xc3,0xA4};
    unsigned int y = 0;

    if (c[0] > 128) {
        y = (c[0] << 8)|c[1];
        switch(y) {
        case 0xC3A4:
            // found0xC3A4
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

You might be running into a few quirks of the C language (C++ isn't really involved here, it inherited these rules).

The `char` type is distinct from both `signed char` and `unsigned char`, and it's implemented-defined whether plain `char` can have negative values (and if so, which). Clearly your system allows `-91`.

A second quirk is that expressions of type `char` are very often promoted to `int`, e.g. when you compare `((char)0xC0) < 0` then the right-hand side is `0`, an `int`, so the left-hand side is also promoted to `int`.

This isn't  particular to UTF-8. ISO-8859-x has the same issue.

Comment: It is not the issue here

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I'll take that into account.